# Title, Menu items not showing on ActionBar inside a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I added the custom toolbar in xml and then added it as Actionbar in fragment.
But it's not showing anything from Title to Menus. The only actionbar is visible

Here is my xml code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <!-- Must be last for right layering display -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And here is my java code

```
public class searchView extends Fragment{

    Toolbar search;
    MaterialSearchView search_view;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_view,container,false);
        FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_view, container, false);

        search = (Toolbar)layout.findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(search);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Contacts");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return v;
    }
}
```

In these code I called the fragment in MainActivity On Bottombar click

```
  else if (position==1){
                    searchView f = new searchView();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout,f).commit();
                }
                return true;
```

Comment: I will suggest to you can add MenuItem on Activity . Can you paste code of your fragment calling activity class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Toolbar search;
MaterialSearchView search_view;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_view,container,false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    search = (Toolbar)v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(search);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Contacts");

    return v;
}
```

}

to show options menu override

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    //add your  menu here;
    }
```

Comment: I forgot why i was using layout.findviewbyid lol.. At that time it was giving some error whule using v.findviewbyid.. But thanx now it's working